# Why doesn't my clojure.contrib.sql/update-values query work?

Tags: oracle, clojure

I thought the query is correct and I printed out every parameter before the call I used to make sure it is in fact a string i'm looking for.

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.sql/update-values

```
(clojure.contrib.sql/with-connection db (
(clojure.contrib.sql/update-values "tableName" ["column1=?" (nth contentVals 0) "column2=?" (nth contentVals 1) "column3=?" (nth contentVals 2)] {"column1" (nth submittedRow 0) "column2" (nth submittedRow 1) "column3" (nth submittedRow 2)}))
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What happens when the code runs?  Is there an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out. 
The following is correct.

```
(sql/update-values "tableName" ["column1=? AND column2=? AND column3=?" (nth contentVals 0) (nth contentVals 1) (nth contentVals 2) {:column1 (nth submittedRow 0) :column2 (nth submittedRow 1) :column3 (nth submittedRow 2)})
```